# Is it possible to send different subset of weights to different clients?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to use tensorflow-federated to select different subset of weights at the server and send them to the clients. The clients then would train and send back the trained weights. The server aggregates the results and starts a new communication round.

The main problem is that I cannot access the numpy version of the weights and therefore I don't know how to access a subset of them for each layer. I tried using tf.gather_nd and tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update to perform selection and update, but they only work for tensors, and not lists of tensors (as the server_state is in tensorflow-federated).

Does anyone have any hint to solve this problem? Is it even possible to send *different* weights to each client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow correctly, a way to write the high-level computation being described in the TFF type shorthand would be:

```py
@tff.federated_computation(...)
def run_one_round(server_state, client_datasets):
  weights_subset = tff.federated_map(subset_fn, server_state)
  clients_weights_subset = tff.federated_broadcast(weights_subset)
  client_models = tff.federated_map(client_training_fn, 
                                    (clients_weights_subset, client_datasets))
  aggregated_update = tff.federated_aggregate(client_models, ...)
  new_server_state = tff.federated_map(apply_aggregated_update_fn, server_state)
  return new_server_state
```

If this is true, it seems like the majority of the work needs to happen in `subset_fn` which takes the server state and returns a subset of the global mode weights.  Generally a model is a structure (`list` or `dict`, possibly nested) of [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), which as you observed cannot be used as an argument to [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) or [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update). However, they can be be applied pointwise to the structure of tensors uses [`tf.nest.map_structure`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nest/map_structure). For example, selecting the value at [0, 0] from a nested structure of three tensors:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pprint
struct_of_tensors = {
    'trainable': [tf.constant([[2.0, 4.0, 6.0]]), tf.constant([[5.0]])],
    'non_trainable': [tf.constant([[1.0]])],
}
pprint.pprint(tf.nest.map_structure(
    lambda tensor: tf.gather_nd(params=tensor, indices=[[0, 0]]),
    struct_of_tensors))

>>> {'non_trainable': [<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.], dtype=float32)>],
     'trainable': [<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([2.], dtype=float32)>,
                   <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([5.], dtype=float32)>]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just noticed that with tff.federated_broadcast() all the clients would receive the same weights. Supposing that I had different weights for different clients (e.g., in a list), how could I send them to the clients?

Comment: In this case you could create two subsets with `subset_fn` and have two different broadcasts. `run_one_round(...)` would need to take and additional dataset argument for the other subset of clients, so something like `def run_one_round(server_state, client_a_datasets, client_b_datasets)`.

Comment: I'm actually trying to send a different subsets of weights (defined by a list of boolean masks) for each client. I think splitting the dataset would be impractical. Do you think there could be a different solution?

Comment: The semantics of `tff.federated_broadcast` is to broadcast the _same_ value to a set of clients (a one-to-many) operation. The only way I can think of at the moment is to have a broadcast per client, with a different weight subset argument. Keep in mind there can be scaling concerns with each client getting different weights, either using a lot more memory, or sequentially broadcasting one subset at a time.